# How to create a session for Run Dialog in Appium?

Tags: unit-testing, appium, ui-automation, winappdriver

By using powershell command I can get the `run dialog` program id, which is `Microsoft.Windows.Shell.RunDialog`. However, I can't get this working with the code below. Any idea?

```
DesiredCapabilities desktopCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desktopCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "Microsoft.Windows.Shell.RunDialog");
desktopCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
desktopCapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Windows");

session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desktopCapabilities);
```

Comment: A obvious request: can you please update your question with the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answers from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1163990/where-is-the-windows-run-command-located) post about the run dialog. My best guess is that winappdriver is calling rundll32.exe and that's not the dialog itself.

You could try your luck changing this line

```
desktopCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "Microsoft.Windows.Shell.RunDialog");
```

into

```
desktopCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61");
```

Alternatively, you could get the desktop session and send "windows key + r" to it. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#general-development--best-practices) is how you can get the desktop session.

Comment: Thanks @PixelPlex! Change to `rundll32.exe` didn't work. However, keyboard `win+r` will do the job or create a run dialog session off top level window based from the link you provided. https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#when-and-how-to-attach-to-an-existing-app-window